# Aborted process when testing non-blocking UDP sockets

Tags: c, sockets, memory, memory-management, asyncsocket

I'm building a non-blocking UDP Socket client/server pair. The synopsis is the client sends a txt file across a traffic shaper to the server, the server receives, writes what it receives to a file, and sends back an "ACK" in the format `<Run number>/<Packet number>`. The file that I want to send is 1048576 bytes, all compact into the `string.txt` you'll see below. I also divide the file into packets of 1024 bytes each (1024 packets) and time the send/recvACK process. Now, I'm running into a problem. I've tried sending a relatively small 2048 byte file (2 packets), and everything works as expected. However, when I try to send this gigantic file, I get a `corrupted_size vs. prev_size` error. See full error below. I understand that it's a huge jump, but I expect that it should still be able to work. One key point: **I do not need every single packet to arrive. I just need a sizable amount with NO memory error.** I have tried debugging everything I can, but to no avail. I can't fix that stupid error. I'm running on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 BTW.

Thanks.

Server:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ITOA_BASE_N (sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT + 2)

void error(const char *msg, const char *detail);
void PrintSocketAddress(const struct sockaddr *address, FILE *stream);
void SIGIOHandler(int signalType);
char * itoa_base(char *s, int x, int base);

#define ITOA(x,b) itoa_base((char [ITOA_BASE_N]){0} , (x), (b))

int sock, run, acknum, maxpack; // GLOBAL for signal handler

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if (argc != 5)
    error("Parameter(s)", "<Server Port/Service> <Number of ACKs> <Maximum packet length> <Number of trials>");

  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
  in_port_t service = atoi(argv[1]);
  acknum = atoi(argv[2]);
  maxpack = atoi(argv[3]);
  int trials = atoi(argv[4]); // must coordinate with client
  run = 0;

  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (sock < 0)
    error("socket() failed", "");

  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(service);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
    error("bind() failed", "");

  struct sigaction handler;
  handler.sa_handler = SIGIOHandler;
  if (sigfillset(&handler.sa_mask) < 0)
    error("sigfillset() failed", "mask not set");
  handler.sa_flags = 0;

  if (sigaction(SIGIO, &handler, 0) < 0)
    error("sigaction() failed", "SIGIO behavior unable to be modified");

  if (fcntl(sock, F_SETOWN, getpid()) < 0)
    error("Unable to set process owner to us", "");

  if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK | FASYNC) < 0)
    error(
        "Unable to put client sock into non-blocking/async mode", "");

  for (;;) {
    if (run == trials) {
      close(sock);
      exit(0);
    }
    printf(".");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
  }
}

void error(const char *msg, const char *detail) {
  fputs(msg, stderr);
  if (*detail != '\0') {
    fputs(": ", stderr);
    fputs(detail, stderr);
  }
  fputc('\n', stderr);
  exit(1);
}

void SIGIOHandler(int signalType) {
  printf("\n");
  fclose(fopen("output.txt", "wb"));
  struct sockaddr_in clntAddr;
  socklen_t clntLen = sizeof(clntAddr);
  ssize_t numBytes;
  int packets = 0;
  FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "ab");
  if (fp == NULL)
    error("Error opening file", "");
  char buffer[maxpack];
  char *output = malloc(maxpack * sizeof(char));
  if (output == NULL)
    error("malloc() failed", "");
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  memset(output, 0, sizeof(output));
  do {
    numBytes = recvfrom(sock, buffer, maxpack, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntLen);
    if (numBytes < 0) {
      if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK) // only acceptable error
        error("recvfrom() failed", "");
    } else {
      packets += 1;
      if (packets != 1) {
        output = realloc(output, maxpack * packets * sizeof(char));
        if (output == NULL)
          error("realloc() failed", "");
      }
      memmove(output + maxpack * (packets - 1), buffer, strlen(buffer));

      fprintf(stdout, "Handling client ");
      PrintSocketAddress((struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, stdout);
      fprintf(stdout, "\n\t%s\n", buffer);
    }
  } while (numBytes >= 0);
  run += 1;
  output[strlen(output) - 1] = 0;
  fprintf(fp, "%s", output);

  fclose(fp);
  free(output);

  char *ack = ITOA(run, 10);
  char *append = ITOA(packets, 10);
  strcat(ack, "/");
  strcat(ack, append);
  for (int i = 0; i < acknum; i++) {
    numBytes = sendto(sock, ack, sizeof(ack), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, clntLen);
    if (numBytes < 0)
      error("sendto() failed", "");
  }
}

char * itoa_base(char *s, int x, int base) {
  s += ITOA_BASE_N - 1;
  *s = '\0';
  if (base >= 2 && base <= 36) {
    int x0 = x;
    do {
      *(--s) = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[abs(x % base)];
      x /= base;
    } while (x);
    if (x0 < 0) {
      *(--s) = '-';
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

Client:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

static const unsigned int TIMEOUT_SECS = 2; // Seconds between retransmits

void error(const char *msg, const char *detail);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if ((argc < 6) || (argc > 7))
    error("Parameter(s)", "<Server Address/Name> <Echo File> <Server Port/Service> <Maximum packet length> <Number of trials> [<Seconds between trials>]");

  char *server = argv[1];
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
  if (fp == NULL)
    error("Error opening file", "");

  fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_END);
  unsigned long stringlen = (getc(fp) == '\n' ? (ftell(fp) - 1) : ftell(fp));
  rewind(fp);

  char *string = malloc(stringlen * sizeof(char));
  for (int i = 0; i < stringlen; i++) {
    *(string + i) = fgetc(fp);
  }
  printf("%lu\n", stringlen);

  fclose(fp);

  in_port_t service = atoi(argv[3]);
  int maxpack = atoi(argv[4]);
  int trials = atoi(argv[5]); // must coordinate with server
  if (trials < 1)
    error("invalid trials parameter", "entered a nonpositive number");
  int sleeptime = (argc == 7) ? atoi(argv[6]) : 5;

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (sock < 0)
    error("socket() failed", "");

  struct timeval timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = TIMEOUT_SECS;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;
  if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt() failed", "");
  if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *) &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt() failed", "");

  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  int rc = inet_pton(AF_INET, server, &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
  if (rc == 0)
    error("inet_pton() failed", "invalid address string");
  else if (rc < 0)
    error("inet_pton() failed", "");
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(service);

  for (int num = 0; num < trials; num++) {
    struct timespec start, end;
    uint64_t diff;
    ssize_t numBytes;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) ceil((double) stringlen / maxpack); i++) {
      if (i == 0)
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
      numBytes = sendto(sock, string + i * maxpack, maxpack, 0, (struct sockaddr* ) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
      if (numBytes < 0)
        error("sendto() failed", "");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in fromAddr;
    socklen_t fromAddrlen = sizeof(fromAddr);
    char buffer[strlen(argv[3]) + 1];
    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    do {
      numBytes = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromAddrlen);
      if (numBytes < 0)
        error("recvfrom() failed", "");
      buffer[numBytes] = '\0';
    } while (atoi(buffer) == num);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    diff = 1000000000L * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;

    printf("Received: %s\n", buffer);
    printf("Time: %f ms\n", (double) (diff / (double) 1000000));
    sleep(sleeptime);
  }

  free(string);
  close(sock);

  exit(0);
}

void error(const char *msg, const char *detail) {
  fputs(msg, stderr);
  if (*detail != '\0') {
    fputs(": ", stderr);
    fputs(detail, stderr);
  }
  fputc('\n', stderr);
  exit(1);
}
```

Error:

```c
*** Error in `./test.c': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x08122970 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xb759d377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xb75a32f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6e48a)[0xb75a448a]
./test.c[0x80490c1]
[0xb7709404]
[0xb7709428]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(nanosleep+0x20)[0xb75e63a0]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(sleep+0x6d)[0xb75e62fd]
./test.c[0x8048da3]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xb754e637]
./test.c[0x8048a31]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3145801    /home/ccnx/cgood/New-Sender-Receiver/Book Code/test.c
0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 08:01 3145801    /home/ccnx/cgood/New-Sender-Receiver/Book Code/test.c
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 3145801    /home/ccnx/cgood/New-Sender-Receiver/Book Code/test.c
08122000-08164000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b73e3000-b73ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2490445    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b73ff000-b7400000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 2490445    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7400000-b7421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7421000-b7500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7535000-b7536000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7536000-b76e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2490387    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b76e6000-b76e8000 r--p 001af000 08:01 2490387    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b76e8000-b76e9000 rw-p 001b1000 08:01 2490387    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b76e9000-b76ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7707000-b7709000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7709000-b770a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b770a000-b772d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2490382    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b772d000-b772e000 r--p 00022000 08:01 2490382    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b772e000-b772f000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 2490382    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
bfb49000-bfb6a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Handling client 172.168.4.101-37691Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Hard to say for sure where your bug might be, but this is a candidate: `memmove(output + maxpack * (packets - 1), buffer, strlen(buffer));`. I do not see where the contents of `buffer` are properly null-terminated, `strlen()` might give a much too large value here.

Comment: regarding: `char *string = malloc(stringlen * sizeof(char));`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely not effect.  Suggest removing that expression.. 2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding statements like: `int maxpack = atoi(argv[4]);` the function: `atoi()` does not tell you if it successfully converted a string into an integer.  In general, suggest using: `strtol()` which does tell you if an error occurred

Comment: regarding: `fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_END);
  unsigned long stringlen = (getc(fp) == '\n' ? (ftell(fp) - 1) : ftell(fp));`  Was `fseek()` successful?  The code failed to check that detail

Comment: there is a long list of functions that should not be called inside a signal handler function.  Amongst them is the function: `printf()`  Therefore, the contents of the signal handler function is a problem.  Note: Usually a signal handler function sets a flag and returns.  The main loop of the program checks that flag and acts accordingly.

Comment: the function: `itoa_base()` seems to be trying to emulate the function: `strtol()`  Suggest replacing the function: `itoa_base()` with the `strtol()`

Comment: regarding: `output = realloc(output, maxpack * packets * sizeof(char));`  When calling `realloc()` always assign the returned value to a `temp` variable, so if (when) `realloc` fails, the original pointer to the allocated memory is not lost.  If the returned value is not NULL, then assign the temp variable to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc` fails, the result is a memory leak and any following activity with that (NULL) pointer will cause a seg fault event

Comment: Have you tried running your program with valgrind enabled? It will, in all probability, lead you to the source of the problem.

Comment: @Ctx Yeah, I was worrying about that when I was first running it but I kept trying and I kept on running into errors no matter where I put the terminator and how I did it. That stuff always confused me in regards to which functions send it, the array size to store it, and other things. I tried it with memcpy and strcat too but they didn't work either. Do you have any suggestions for the exact place to put them?

Comment: @user3269249 1. Yeah I know the sizeof simplifies for that type but many people have told be to put it there for good practice anyways. 2. As you see with the other places where I call dynamic memory allocation, I usually do the null check directly afterward, I just forgot for this one. I'll add it but I don't think that that's the root of the problem

Comment: @user3269249 As for the strtol stuff, I see where it come come in handy over atoi (I just hadn't known about it) but I don't see it in place of itoa because notice that itoa converts from integer to string. I'll switch atoi for strtol but again that's probably not the root of the problem because I assure you that I entered in the cmd parameters correctly